# Why does Blazor API call stop working until I rename my API method

Tags: blazor, blazor-webassembly

I have a blazor WASM application with 3 projects: Client, Server, Shared.

As a simplistic example, I'd call my API from the client via:

```
var result = await http.GetAsync($"{controller}/GetAllItems");
```

On the server side my API is defined as:

```
[ApiController]
[Route("[controller]/[action]")]
public class ItemController : Controller

    [HttpGet]
    public async Task<ActionResult<List<POCO>>> GetAllItems()
    {
      var items = await repository.GetItems();
      return Ok(items);
    }
```

This code has been working fine for two weeks.  Until today, when it stopped working.  After debugging, I found that the name: *GetAllItems* no longer worked.

Once I changed the method name from *GetAllItems* to *GetAllItemsNew*, the code worked fine again.

A few hours later, this happened a second time with another method.

Is there a reason why the blazor API would stop routing to specific method names, but continue to work for others?

**EDIT**

Following the advice in the comments, I installed Postman.  I'm unable to connect to my API via Postman.  In my app:

- I added App.UseAuthentication to StartUp.Configure()
- I flagged the Controller as [AllowAnonymous]
- I started running the app in Debug Mode from Visual Studio

In Postman

- I disabled SSL certificate verification
- I performed a GET to localhost:44383/ItemController/GetAllItems

I got back the following error:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no" />
    <title>TestApp</title>
    <base href="/" />
    <link href="css/bootstrap/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
    <link href="css/app.css" rel="stylesheet" />
    <link href="TestApp.Client.styles.css" rel="stylesheet" />
</head>

<body>
    <div id="app">Loading...</div>

    <div id="blazor-error-ui">
        An unhandled error has occurred.
        <a href="" class="reload">Reload</a>
        <a class="dismiss"></a>
    </div>
    <script src="_framework/blazor.webassembly.js"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: What you are saying doesn't make sense.  You are doing something else that is causing whatever problem you are seeing.  Can you use something like postman or make a direct call to the API Url.  You need to consider what you have changed recently.

Comment: And post the exact errors you get.

Comment: Separate the issues to isolate the cause: 1) is the web api working? Maybe use PostMan or similar to query the API directly. 2) If it's working check the WASM app is updated: rebuild and maybe clear the appcache on the browser. Log the detailed errors to a file so you can trace errors. Does it working locally and not on a host? Maybe it's ports, firewall etc.

Comment: Re your edit: That is the blank home page, menaing the URL  in Postman is not valid. You can use the Dev Tools, network to get the actual URL form your app.  Not that the correct URL should work in a Browser as well, showing you the JSon.

Comment: Do you solved? My Blazor API suddenly stopped working with no reason with the same HTML as response.